# PowerPoint 2010: Snapping still happening even after turning off

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, snapping

In PowerPoint 2010, I have turned off "snap objects to grid" and "snap objects to other objects". However, when I draw a line and it goes close to certain points on the perimeter of another object, it still automatically snaps to that object. For example, if the object is a rectangle, it will automatically snap to the halfway points down each side of the rectangle (which appear as little red squares when this happens). How do I prevent this behavior so that there is no "snapping" altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These red dots are called "connection points". I don't know of any way to disable them, but you can override them by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while you draw.

Comment: Holding "Alt" makes them disappear, but does not prevent the snapping...

Comment: It's disabling the visuals of the connection points, but still snapping other shapes to them? Very strange. Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, this Alt trick works but only if the "Grid settings" are turned to "snap to grid". Otherwise it doesn't work. Just so to help you getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

still no perfect answer in Jan 2017.

Let's try one: Copy the problematic object into the clipboard. Paste it back as PNG or EMF. That should neuter those red balls.